# Parsing Binary File to JSON from Excel xlsb file in Javascript

Tags: json, parsing, xlsb

I actually got this working once but then I lost the code to do it and haven't been able to get it working again.

I am able to get the file pretty easily using a $.get(server filepath) and it gives me a bunch of crazy looking data...I've tried various methods to read in binary data as a blob and arrayBuffer but none of these have worked right.

how can I convert this into the actual data and then to JSON similar to what D3.parseCSV does?

I've tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'binary',
        processData: false,
        responseType: 'arrayBuffer',
 }).then(function (data) {
       return data
       }, function (error) {
         alertify.error('There was an error retriving the data');
     });
};
```

which gives me back the same data as just using $.get(url)

I've tried using Sheets.JS and did

```
$.get(filePath).then(function(data) {
XLSX.read(data, {Props: {type: "buffer"}}) 
})
```

and get a "Unrecognized type [object Object]" error.

If I use type: "binary" I get "undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

I've tried manipulating it with the following:

```
                var buf = new ArrayBuffer(csvData.length * 2);
                var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
                for (var j = 0; j < csvData.length; j++) {
                    bufView[j] = csvData.charCodeAt(j);
                }
                var myData = buf;
```

I've tried using decoder("utf-8") and then decoder.decode(csvData)...

haven't gotten anything to work.

Comment: Please share some of your not working code. The basic question and `$.get(server filepath)` isn't much to work with.

Comment: https://docs.sheetjs.com/#json

Comment: @Slai I just tried that and it returned an empty array  [ ]